# Error when trying to declare a variable as a parameter. No problem when i try to declare it inside the function

Tags: php, parameters, symfony1, criteria, propel

I have this function:

```
public static function getOrdini($sort_order = 4)
{

    $con = Propel::getConnection();
    $sql = "select * from shop_orders LEFT JOIN shop_orders_total
            ON
            shop_orders.orders_id = shop_orders_total.orders_id
            AND
            shop_orders_total.sort_order = :sort_order";
    $stmt = $con->prepare($sql);

    $result = $stmt->execute(array(':sort_order' => $sort_order));
    $ordini = self::populateObjects($stmt);


    return $ordini;

}
```

When I call it I get this error:

> ( ! ) Catchable fatal error: Object of
>   class Criteria could not be converted
>   to string in
>   /home/javier/Aptana_Studio_Workspace/dev_repo/lib/vendor/symfony/lib/plugins/sfPropelPlugin/lib/vendor/propel/util/DebugPDOStatement.php
>   on line 99

but if write the function in this way below I don't get any error:

```
public static function getOrdini()
{
    $sort_order = 4;            
    $con = Propel::getConnection();
    ...
```

Any idea?

Regards

Javi

Answer (score 0):

No bug in the above code it is okay. I tried passing value in the static method and it is fine the error is being generated from the other part of your code checking in the class `Criteria`  would help you here is nothing in the posted.

Ask to `propel, symfony`. here someone is facing the same problem 
 http://symfonyexperts.com/question/show/id/51